# autoscaling with queues does not start

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services, azure-autoscaling-block

so my environment is set in cloud service with 2 instances of worker role which process messages from service bus queue.I have also set up autoscaling block to increase instances when an instance has more than 10 messages to handle.
here are steps i take.
I push messages to a queue about 1000
current all my messages are unprocessed as my instances are not up.
i publish the worker role with 2 instances, and when they are up,they start reading messages correctly.
then i configure autoscaling in above stated rule for queues and 10 messages per instance.

What I excpected was since the instances already have more than they can handle, azure should start spinning up new instance.but this doesnt happen untill at least 10-15 minutes after my first two instances are up.

What could be the reason behind this and any algorithm on microsoft side?

Comment: Have you read this article - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-scale/? My guess is that your issue is somehow related to configuration (either the time period since last autoscale operation has not elapsed or the max number of messages to trigger autoscaling is configured very high).

Comment: yup have read this.. in my case, time since last autoscale is configured minimum(5 minutes)..issues is , I understand that, it takes azure anything upto 10 minutes around to get new instance running.. but i expected that the provisioning would start and display in portal immediately when the queue message number is high..which it doesnt.or I interpret the documentation incorrectly